# Is there a term for the convergent evolution of homonyms?

Tags: homonyms

Some homonyms, like "punch", originated in different languages with different spellings. The violent act "punch" comes from the English word "pounce", while the beverage "punch" comes from the Hindi word "pañc" ([citation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punch_%28drink%29#History)).

Is there a name for this phenomenon? It seems like the opposite of [polysemy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysemy), in which a single word from a common origin takes on multiple related meanings.

Comment: I'm sorry but do you mean homophones?

Comment: @KCH OP's use of 'homonym' here seems standard.

Comment: I've used 'convergent evolution' myself before now.

Comment: A friend told me that "false cognate" might be the applicable term, though I feel like that's most commonly used for words in different languages.

Comment: I think the best word would be _coincidence_. There are only so many short words, it's inevitable that some different concepts will end up with similar words, and eventually evolve to the same ones.

Comment: It seems plausible that an introduced foreign word, not easily pronounced and initially unfamiliar, might, through mishearing and misspeaking, tend toward a similar word already used in the language. But it's not clear to me why that process would be conceptually connected to the already used word's previous evolution within the language.

Answer (score 1):

Homographs: [a word of the same written form as another but of different meaning and usually origin, whether pronounced the same way or not, as bear 1  “to carry; support” and bear 2  “animal” or lead 1  “to conduct” and lead 2  “metal.”](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Homograph)

Comment: While this fits, it's a bit too broad: I'm looking for the term that specifically means "homonyms with different origins".

Comment: @perimosocordiae Homonyms by the usual definition **must** have different origins. You appeared to be asking for a term for the morphological shifts that brought both Old English beran and Old English bera to 'bear' say; 'convergent evolution' (_to_ homonyms) is the closest I can manage.

Comment: Homonyms and homographs are the result, he seems to be asking for a term for the process in language evolution that produces them.